# Set bounds on a window that has an id

Tags: google-chrome-app

My app has a settings window, I want this window to be unique so that a user cannot display two settings windows at the same time. The problem is that I also want the window to be centered compared to the main window. I use this code (in the JS of the main window):

```
chrome.app.window.create("settings.html",
   {
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        bounds: {
            left: Math.round((window.screenX + (($(window).width() - 498) / 2))), // Perfect left position.
            top: Math.round((window.screenY + (($(window).height() - 664) / 2))), // Perfect top position.
            width: 498,
            height: 664
        },
        frame : "none",
        id: "settings",
        resizable: false
    }
);
```

The problem is that if an `id` is specified and a window with a matching `id` has been shown before, the remembered `bounds` will be used but I would prefer to set the bounds myself at every creation with the bounds option. Thus if the user moves the window and closes it the position would still be "perfect" at the next creation. Is there a solution to have this behavior?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't override this.

You can reposition the window immediately on creation in the callback, using `outerBounds.setPosition`:

```
chrome.app.window.create(
  "settings.html",
  {/*...*/},
  function(win) {
    win.outerBounds.setPosition(
      /*left, top*/
    );
  }
);
```

By the way, `bounds` is deprecated, you should switch to using `innerBounds`/`outerBounds`.

---

Alternatively, you can try to implement your own ID system. Don't use an ID, and check if the window you need is open (identifying it somehow) before creating it.

Comment: if you don't use an id, how can you check for it to see if it is already opened? And also, when you reload the app, the new created window remembers the past bounds (for instance if I have resized it manually). It is an error you cannot override this.